# How to create this specific portfolio business card with html and css

Tags: html, css, alignment, blur, portfolio

I'm trying to copy the business card below for a portfolio website.
The part that i need is the square photo that's blurred, with the centered (same) photo inside.

I get stucked at the following things:

- css blur makes edges smooth, but i want straight edges
- css blur wil also blur the children elements, so in this case the small photo and text.

*I like to be efficient with my code, not too much use of pixels because it will not be responsive. and trying to have clean code and more usage of css selectors instead of div id's and classes.*

I hope someone can help me out!

See here the example image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/02NWz.jpg

#### EDIT:

I've tried several things but no good results. This is what I got now:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images\">

    <title>Jobbe Maas</title>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="personal-card">
            <!-- photo -->
            <div class="photo-wrapper">
                <img class="photo-big" src="images/me.jpg">
                <img class="photo-small" src="images/me.jpg">
            </div>

            <!-- info -->

        </div>

        <!-- <footer>&copy; Jobbe Maas 2014</footer> -->

        <!-- Scripts at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cw = $('.photo-wrapper').width();
            $('.photo-wrapper').css({
                'height': cw + 'px'
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.personal-card {
background-color: grey;
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
margin: 10% auto;
}

.photo-wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.photo-big {
filter: blur(8px) sepia(25%) grayscale(25%);
-webkit-filter: blur(8px) sepia(25%) grayscale(25%);
-moz-filter: blur(8px) sepia(25%) grayscale(25%);
-o-filter: blur(8px) sepia(25%) grayscale(25%);
-ms-filter: blur(8px) sepia(25%) grayscale(25%);

width: 110%;
height: 110%;
margin: -10px -15px -15px -10px;
}
```

Comment: `.photo-wrapper` will expand to the size of its contents, showing the edges. Try making it smaller than the image by specifying `position: relative;` along with `width` and `height` to constrain is causing the `overflow: hidden` to actually crop.

Comment: Thanks! The edges are fine now. But how can i get the smaller picture inside, in the middle (and on top of) the big picture?
by the way: you can see the website live here: http://jobbemaas.nl/portfolio/

Comment: add a CSS class for `.photo-wrapper .photo-small` and give it a `position: absolute;` and `top:` and `left:` values to set it's position relative to .photo-wrapper (not knowing the size of your images I can't give the actual CSS)

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to center the small image, you could do it responsively with `top`, `left` and negative `margin`s. Try adding something like this to your small photo:

```css
.photo-small {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seiseises/59sWZ/). Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

> [...] and trying to have clean code and more usage of css selectors instead of div id's and classes.

I forgot that part. You could get rid of your `.photo-big` and `.photo-small` classes and select them with:

```css
.photo-wrapper > img:first-child { ... }
.photo-wrapper > img:last-child { ... }
```